# Why are there so many different coordinate systems?

Tags: coordinate-system, gps

Why is there not a standardized system worldwide or at least one per country?

It feels such an inefficient process to have to identify what a particular coordinate means, but perhaps there is a good reason behind it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are some reasons which depend of what you want do with your geographic data:

- Preserving direction (azimuthal or zenithal), a trait possible only from one or two points to every other point
- Preserving shape locally (conformal or orthomorphic)
- Preserving area (equal-area or equiareal or equivalent or authalic)
- Preserving distance (equidistant), a trait possible only between one or two points and every other point
- Preserving shortest route, a trait preserved only by the gnomonic projection

Because the sphere is not a developable surface, it is impossible to construct a map projection that is both equal-area and conformal.

For details, you should have a look to this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) .